# Setting a checkbox's state according to column in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I was just wondering how to either tick or untick a check box according to the value `True` or `False` in a `GridView`. Similar to writing the value in a `TextBox`

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

but for

```
checkBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

if `True = Tick`, if `False = Untick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkBox1.Checked = true;
```

or

```
checkBox1.Checked = false;
```

Full code would be something like:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "TRUE")
{
    checkBox1.Checked = true;
} 
else if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "FALSE")
{
    checkBox1.Checked = false;
}
```

You can't do the code you wrote because the data you pulled from the data grid view is a string and `.Checked` requires a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to convert the result to boolean.
>   In [`Gridview.CellValueChangedEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) add code

```
checkBox1.Checked = (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "TRUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isChecked;
bool.TryParse(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out isChecked);
checkBox1.Checked = isChecked;
```

This means if your string ever changes to "True" or "true" it will still be able to Parse it as a boolean instead of just doing a string check against "TRUE" which could easily break futher down the line.

Comment: How can This break ->  ToUpper() == "TRUE" ?